# Why I can't call multiple stored procedures consecutively with Django and Postgres

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, commit, procedure

I have a class in python, the class has the following methods

```py
self.__evaluateAmenityBuffers()
self.__evaluateTransitBuffers()
self.__evaluateRoadsBuffers()
self.__evaluateRiskBuffers()
self.__EvaluateJobsBuffer()
```

in each method I call a stored procedure with Django, the code is similar to the next one

```py
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.callproc("urbper_buffer_amenities", [self.scenario])
```

the issue I am facing with is that only the first method writes its changes in the data base, If I comment the first method, the second one works but the next methods are executed but their chages are not stored in the database.
¿could you help to find out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running a `cur.commit()` after each one?

Comment: Yes, I have tryied that one too but it didn't work.